# Not sure how to write this function in hooks form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am converting a code from class to functional component. I am unsure as to how I would convert the code below into a hooks function.

```
  applyFilter = () => {
  const { filterLimit: value, lessThanOrGreaterThan } = this.state;
  const isLessThan = lessThanOrGreaterThan === "lessThan";

  // update instance variable
  this.state.datas = this.state.datas.map(v => {
    if (isLessThan ? v <= value : v >= value) return v;
    return 0;
  });

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    datas: this.state.datas,
  }));
  }
```

I have declared the used variables as hooks as follows-

```
const [filterLimit, setfilterLimit] = useState(100);
const [lessThanOrGreaterThan, setlessThanOrGreaterThan] = useState('lessThan');
const [datas, setDatas] = useState([12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 10])
```

Comment: Why do you want this to be a hook?

Comment: @szczocik Lol why not?

Comment: ' I am converting a code from functional component to class ' ... It seems like you do the inverse ... nope ?

Comment: Because it looks like the function is the callback function for some button or something and it interacts with the data located in that component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got most of is. Looks like you just need to swap out the references to state with the props you've already defined.

```
const [filterLimit, setfilterLimit] = useState(100);
const [lessThanOrGreaterThan, setlessThanOrGreaterThan] = useState('lessThan');
const [datas, setDatas] = useState([12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 10])

const applyFilter = () => {
    const isLessThan = lessThanOrGreaterThan === "lessThan";

    // update instance variable
    const newDatas = datas.map(v => {
    if (isLessThan ? v <= value : v >= value) return v;
        return 0;
    });

    setDatas(newDatas);
}
```